# Proof for additivity of cumulants

Tags: pr.probability

If one does not define cumulants via the cumulant generating function (cgf), e.g. because the cgf does not exist, then an alternative way is to use the recusion
\begin{align*}
\kappa_n=\mu'_n-\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose m-1}\kappa_m \mu_{n-m}',
\end{align*}
where $\mu_i'$ denotes the $i$th uncentered moment.

For this definition, what is the best way to show that the cumulants are additive under an independence assumption? More precisely, how do we show that
\begin{align*}
  \kappa_n(X+Y) = \kappa_n(X) + \kappa_n(Y),
\end{align*}
if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables?

Answer (score 7):

I assume all your moments are finite. In that case, a simple proof is to approximate your random variable by truncation, use the additivity for the approximated cummulants, and then pass to the limit using dominated convergence.

Comment: would an induction actually work?

Comment: @seno44 I see no reason why the binomial theorem would not give you what you want by induction.